# Custom dimension in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to create a custom dimension in Google Analytics based off a URL part?

I have a series of URLs in the format `/title/id/xx` where I want to group by the `id` portion. I know I can set up a content group for each `id` however this is cumbersome as we have so many of them and they keep growing.

Is there any way to make this more dynamic so that I can use it in a custom report?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would to create a new view under your UA property with a filter that is configured as the following:

Filter type: Predefined

Include only | Traffic to the hostname | That Begin With

then set your hostname using regular expression for your URI

for example in your case will likely be ^/title/id/(.)

You can read more about regular expressions here:
[Google Answers](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en)

Comment: Interesting angle. Would this allow me to then report on the /id/ report and group anything under that, without having to specify each individual ID?

Comment: That is the idea, just telling it to capture everything that contains /title/id/ request URI and count it under that view. Best of luck -p

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. With each pageview you send, you would need to capture, via some JS, the specific part of the string you are interested in and then push that into a CD. The CD would be hit-scoped.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Would this do anything to update historical data though?

Comment: No, historical data would not be altered.